# Compare and find similar row in two columns (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, similarity

I have a table with over million rows. Two of the columns have similar text in them. For example:

Column1 - [value] cat is sick
Column2 - the cat is sick

Both values are similar. I want to know a query that can return me the rows of these two columns with similar values. I tried following:

```
select * from table where column1 like 'column2'
```

However, it didn't find such cases.

Comment: Can you have something like "the cat is very sick"?

Comment: It is possible. However that might be more difficult. If I can find the solution for that one as well then it is awesome Otherwise, solution for current/mentioned problem would be enough as well.

Comment: You will need to carefully define *similar* for your case.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
select *
from table
where column1 like '%' + column2 + '%';
```

Your query is looking for values where the value of `column1` is the string `'column2'`.

Comment: i already mentioned in my question that i tried this. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3404047 . . . Not at all.  This query is quite different from what is in the question.